# How do I get a parent-group alias as token for the Pathauto module?

Tags: 8, path-aliases, group

When a user sets his groups alias to lets say "mynewgroup" you can view the group at www.example.com/mynewgroup.

How to set pathauto presets to create www.example.com/mynewgroup/mynewgroupcontent as a path for a newly created group-content?

I can not find a token for parent's group alias.
I can only find [group_content:gid:entity:url] - but this provides full path and not only the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at the moment (unless you make it yourself), there is an issue in the module's issue queue though that also has a patch that might work:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2774827